# Navigation panel on top and bottom both in Flexigrid

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

How can I implement in flexigrid, to show a navigation panel on top and bottom **both**?
I find a [solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/flexigrid/drPeB4o3270/nUHAhNVdxncJ) to change between top and bottom, but it doens't works with both.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested but from the solution you linked to it should work like this: replace the line:  '$(g.bDiv).after(g.pDiv);' with:

```
var navClone = $(g.pDiv).clone(true);
$(g.bDiv).prepend(g.pDiv).after(navClone);
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't works.
It puts the nav.bar to the first line of the list.